# kendu grid integration with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, kendo-ui

I am integrating Kendo UI with my aplication, which is in PHP based on CodeIgniter framework. I am able to retrieve the data from the controller and display in the Kendo Grid, but I am not able to send the selected grid data to my controller to perform other operation ie. create, destroy, or update. I searched on google regarding this, but did not get any useful post.

So if any one have idea about how to send the data from client side and receive on server side controller, then please revert back to me. I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

## view

```
read: {
      url: 'http://urdomain/ursystemname/index.php/schoolC/getjson',
      datatype: 'json',
      type: 'GET'
   },
```

## controller studentC

```
public function getjson()
    {
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        echo $this->SchoolM->get_allJsonData();
    }
```

## model schoolM

```
function get_allJsonData()
    {
        $arr = array();
        $this->db->from('school');
        $this->db->order_by("school_name", "asc");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        foreach($query->result_object() as $rows )
        {
            $arr[] = $rows;
        }
        return "{\"data\":" .json_encode($arr). "}";
    }
```

i hope it help

Comment: Thanks. My application was able to read the data. Only problem was in update, delete and create operation. But i fixed it some how and now it is working absolutely fine. Now i am sending all the Ajax request from inside the parameterMap. mow all CRUD operations are working.......thanks once again for respond.